Answering student's question that is already in the upcoming exam
I am teaching a course and classes are over. I have already created and printed the final exam. One of my students emailed me with a question that happens to be identical to one of the questions in the exam.
I am unsure how to handle this situation. Should I respond to the student's email, knowing that it might give them an advantage and potentially be unfair to other students? Or would it be better to ignore the email entirely to maintain fairness?
What is the best course of action in such a scenario?

"knowing that it might [...] be unfair to other students?" How might this be unfair?

This is pretty common when lazy tutors endlessly recycle past papers. It becomes very easy to guess what questions are going to be asked.

Do you think this is all just a coincidence, or could your upcoming exam have leaked out to the students (either directly, or indirectly due to reusing questions from a few years ago)? The best course of action is very different depending on if this is an attempt to cheat or not.

I had this happen in high school. A friend asked the teacher how to do a particular question, which later turned out to be on the exam. The teacher answered it.

I've given the exact same problem on a (long) practice exam as on the exam itself and students still couldn't do it. This has happened multiple times. I think you're worrying a bit too much.

A useful answer need not be comprehensive.

Okay: Imagine being the student who earnestly asked a question they were struggling with only to have the instructor refuse to answer it and then put it on the exam. They won't know you already made the test, so it will look personal to them—like you stole the question from them after refusing to help them with it. It will look like a combination of cruelty and deliberate sabotage. And if they push back, are you going to explain to them (and the chair/dean they drag in) that this all basically happened because you didn't want to reprint an exam and that was more important than helping them?

I once studied on a (computer science) course where they tried to make questions unpredictable (by random selection if necessary). On one occasion they repeated a question from one paper to the next. Good students did better on the second one, because they had gone home and thought about their answer to the first.

@TooTea - I studied my department's past papers and noticed a significant pattern. I revised heavily in the direction that I expected to see on exam day, and was rewarded with a solid grade. Did I cheat?

@Valorum No, I certainly wouldn't say so. Cheating would require somehow getting hold of the current version before the exam. Say sneaking into the teacher's office and taking a photo of the paper,or having a TA friend share a copy with you.

@Valorum: Is there a particular dialect of English that uses "revision" in this way (which I would consider wrong, it should be "review"...  view and vision are related but review and revision are not)?  Or was it auto-correct-induced?  I ask because the blockquote in Allure's answer uses it identically.

@BenVoigt British English uses "revise" in roughly the same way US English uses "study"

If it is true that your answering the student's question gives them an advantage, then I would argue that it is a fair advantage. They are studying diligently for the exam and making use of the support resources being offered to them, including emailing the professor with questions. Any knowledge that they obtain through this process is fairly obtained and if they are then asked about it on the exam and demonstrate that they have acquired it, they fully deserve the points. So there is no reason to treat this question any differently from any other question a student might ask you.
Moreover, as an instructor you have two dual roles, to teach the students knowledge and to assess their knowledge. Intentionally withholding knowledge from the student in order to (ostensibly) increase the fairness of your assessment method goes against your responsibility as a teacher of knowledge. To me, that seems backwards: I see myself as a teacher first and as an evaluator of knowledge second (or perhaps third or fourth - it is an important aspect of my job, to be sure, but not what I would regard as the highest priority). So again, from a philosophical point of view I think it's misguided to intentionally refrain to answer a question from a student because of considerations related to testing.
Of course, if you do answer the question, you shouldn't tell the student that it will be on the exam! Just treat it as any other question.

This is the right approach. Generally, I would try to design the exam and then "forget" about it. Your answers to students should be the same as if they asked some other lecturer who has never seen the exam.

I have very occasionally heard of professors who don't answer questions between the end of class and the final. Not necessarily endorsing this plan, nor would doing it out of the blue be very fair, but I have heard of it.

@AzorAhai if they are not answering any questions, I’d guess this is more an issue of the professor wanting/needing a break from teaching-related duties than some deep philosophical conviction related to pedagogy.

@DanRomik Perhaps. This was a decade ago and not my philosophy.

In a sense, if OP had and followed a policy of not answering questions that are on the exams, he would be giving the student arguably more of an advantage by not answering the question, because then the student might deduce that the question is likely to be on the exam if they don't get an answer. A model answer is probably easy to obtain for the student anyway from other sources, if they are persistent about it.

I have two suggestions, one short term and the other long.
The short term answer is consistent with my general policy that students should be given minimal answers to questions. The answers send them back to learning materials so that they need to do a bit of work, hopefully leading to some insight. Full answers are a bit too "lazy" for my taste.
But a "minimal answer" is not something like "Go look at the textbook". It takes thought to understand what is blocking the student's progress and points them in the direction of a solution without giving the solution. "How does the mean value theorem apply here?" for example. It takes a thinking person to give such answers and is actually a bit harder than just giving the solution.  Seeing answers has much less educational value than working out the answers, even with hints.
But, you should provide some answer to the student no matter how you do it. Hopefully the exam as a whole won't be much affected by this and also hopefully your grading scheme isn't competitive so that a small advantage for one implies a disadvantage for others. Learning isn't, or shouldn't be a competition.
Note that not providing an answer at all is, itself, a hint to the student which keys them to the likelihood that something similar is on the exam.
Also note that you don't normally know what students have most recently thought about when the exam is given. This is an exception, but the good students will presumably be looking for answers to likely questions wherever they think to find them.
The long term solution, too late for you now, is to communicate with students via a mailing list (or similar), to which all are subscribed. Then every question and every answer is seen by all students simultaneously. I used this successfully for many years. I also had the policy that students could answer questions as well as ask them, so I only needed to monitor posts for incorrect answers. But, again, answers there from me were minimal.
I've assumed that changing the exam isn't an option and would not recommend that it be changed.

Can I ask, what is your purpose as a teacher? If you only give "minimal answers", and, I suppose, not sticking to the Moore system, then what's the difference between you and a text-to-speech add-on for a textbook?

@denist. there is an important distinction to be made between answering a question during the term and answering a question during the exam period.  Students had the entire term to ask questions.

@denist., I think about what is misleading or troubling the student before I answer and my answer is intended to guide them to better understanding. I think, unlike an AI. And this is my practice during the term as well. Seeing an answer isn't learning how to develop the answer. My "minimal" answer isn't ever "Go look at the text." But it might be a question in response to a question: "What does the mean value theorem tell you here?".

Nothing good in this answer. Denying a student an explanation is only an option when 1) you have an ideal course, 2) the course is perfectly consistent with a textbook, 3) all your students never get ill or be absent due to important reasons.

@yarchik I don’t deny them an explanation. I guide them to insight, which takes work. I deliver an education, not “facts.”

@yarick this answer is particularly important when a choose isn't consistent with a textbook, or rather,  when no textbook exists. Helping a student find the relevant primary sources and seeing how those sides are relevant to the question, but leaving it to the student to actuality work it out best fulfills the role of a HE teacher in teaching students how to think and research.

Credits to Its Me:

A very similar thing happened with me in the last year of my undergrad. The professor had given an exercise in the class as an homework. The question wasn't too hard, but still it was on the harder side. None of us were able to solve it properly; all of us just had some intuitive idea. After few days everybody just forgot about that problem. But before the final exam, as I was doing my revision, I again decided to give it a try, but, again, no luck.
Few hours before the exam I went to the professor's office to ask him about this problem and he told me the solution. To my surprise, that exact same question appeared as a bonus (or "challenging") question in the exam.
Obviously I was able to solve it and my other classmates couldn't. Then, after the exam, I talked to the professor about this and he said,"well, lucky you".

Or, as Andreas Blass wrote in a comment to that answer:

If you've already composed an exam and then a student asks you a question that's on the exam, you answer the question and you leave it in the exam.


Something similar happened to me as an instructor: during an exam review, a student asked a question that I knew was going to be on the test. I answered the question without any hesitation and did not change the exam at all. Those who read the exam review slides closely would have an "advantage", but this advantage was available to everyone in the class since they all had access to the exam review slides even if they did not attend the exam review.

Happened to me as an undergrad, due to either intention or laziness. There was a type of problem that was the capstone of the class, it was relevant and used a broad selection of concepts that were taught. One such problem was assigned for homework. The review guide listed the exact same problem. As it seemed so important, we got the TA to solve it in the review session. I put the solution on my equation sheet. The problem showed up on the final, not unexpectedly, but with the exact same numbers. I decided to add some random erasures and crossed out 1+1=3 mistakes.

What I do is that all questions of this type should be posted on our forum (all courses have some type of discussion board on Canvas). So when students ask me questions, I tell them to post it on the discussion board.
Then I, my TAs, or preferably other students answer the question.
That way, no student get an advantage of asking me questions (in theory).

If, as likely in this case, you don't normally use the discussion board, you can just send an email to all the students along the lines of "Multiple people have got stuck with xyz question" (even if only one student has), if you don't want to have any chance of being percieved as unfairly helping the student, without penalizing them for having had difficulties with that specific question.

Props to this student for diligence --- answer the question as normal
You should answer the question just as with any other question that a student would ask about the course material.  The resulting advantage the student accrues on the examination results from their diligence in investigating problems that other students did not investigate.  As a general rule, if a student is diligent and examines a broad range of practice questions during their study period then some of them will be the same or similar to examination questions.  That is the general pattern in any study session preceeding examinations.  That outcome is perfectly fair and is a result of diligence in studying the course material --- it is not appropriate to withhold normal teaching support to avoid this outcome.

You should answer the question and not change the final.  Kudos for the student to study, and the student should not be penalized for asking a question.
On the other hand, I always tell students they have until 72hrs before the exam to ask questions; I do not answer questions too close to the exam to avoid the situation you are in.  I start a draft exam well ahead of this but I finish the final version after the question window is closed.
This is a reaction to a situation where, one year, I had a student in my office until 30mins before the exam trying to extract info about the contents of the final.  After explaining my logic to every class since, I’ve never had issues or complaints with this policy.  In fact because students know of this policy they tend to start studying earlier rather than later.

If I come up with a question: I make sure it's not identical to one on the test.
If a student comes up with any question: it's fair game.

Instead of considering this as an isolated situation, consider which policy would be fairer in general.
If your policy is to refuse to answer questions which will appear on the exam, then a student who gets a refusal, can infer that the question they asked will appear on the exam. That student can then put more effort into solving that question, or look for a solution elsewhere, and memorise it for the exam.
Other answerers have explained why answering the question does not give an unfair advantage to that student. But even if you think there is something unfair about answering the question, it is much more important to not give away clues about what will be on the exam. If you (indirectly) tell the student that their question will appear on the exam, then you give that student knowledge they really shouldn't have.
A better way to address your concern might be to use a shared forum for Q&As, so that all students can see the answers you give, rather than provide them only to the one student who asked it.

It happened to me as a student: I am from a country where exams are not such important matters and mostly there to judge your level, make you progress and study.
The professor answered the question to the best of their ability. When I realized that the question was in the test, I answered it using the explanation from the professor and probably got 1 additional point out of 20 as a result. Is this such a big deal?
I would rather think that this is the rewards for curiosity of the student. What would be unfair would be to answer some students and not others (if multiple asked). Chances are that this student will share this knowledge with others, ultimately increasing the level of your class, is this not the aim?

I don't fully get this, what's the point of giving you 1 out of 20 if you answered the question (presumably) right?

I'm also confused by this second paragraph. Do you mean you got few points on that question, or that the question you got the answer to was worth 1 point with a total of 20 points on the exam?

Actually, I interpreted the "1 out of 20" to mean an additional point. But even that estimate would be a guess most likely.

1 additional point out of 20
